# Listening for addEventListener calls for a custom event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent

I'm trying to build a custom drag event. Here's my initial pseudocode, note that I left event cleaning up out.

```
var dragEvent = new CustomEvent("drag");
var anArbitrairyElement = document.querySelector(".box");

anArbitrairyElement.addEventListener("drag", function () {
    console.log("event received");
});

(function () {
    var dragEventListeners = [];

    window.addEventListener("mousedown", function (mousedownEvent) {
        dragEventListeners.forEach(function (target) {
            if (mousedownEvent.target === target) {
                window.addEventListener("mousemove", function (mousemoveEvent) {
                    target.dispatchEvent(dragEvent);
                });
            }

            // ...
        });        
    });

    // does something like this exist?
    onDragEventAdded(function (listenerElement) {
        dragEventListeners.push(listenerElement);
    });
}());
```

Is there any way I can listen to `addEventListener` calls without overwriting the `addEventListener` function itself? The solution needs to end-up in this being possible:

```
document.querySelector(".someElement").addEventListener("drag", ...);
```

Otherwise, is there another way how I could achieve the desired behavior of creating a custom drag event?

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? Have list of all elements which listen to  your custom event?

Comment: @Stepashka Yes, I don't know how I would implement a custom drag event otherwise.

Comment: In that case, limiting your `dragEventListeners` variable to the function scope is a no no.

Comment: @JonathanBrooks I edited out my previous scoping mistake, `dragEventListeners` is in scope both within the mousedown handler and the `onDragEventAdded` handler.

Comment: Do I understand your code correctly? There are some elements on the page. When user tries to drag any of them (click on mouse and start moving the mouse) you want it to dispatch your custom event. This event should be received by anArbitrairyElement. is it correct?

Comment: My advice would be to listen for changes on a custom array factory, adding an event handler to each item that's pushed onto the array. will work on an example - side note, why is your targets array set to empty? Your event listener has nothing to iterate over.

Comment: @Stepashka almost, the drag event should only fire on the element that got clicked on initially, so if you click and drag `anArbitrairyElement`, it should fire only for `anArbitrairyElement`, the array is just the listener pattern.

@JonathanBrooks Ah sorry, I should have mentioned that I wanted to do this using native api's only.. I've implemented a custom drag event many times before, I'm getting kind of tired of reimplementing ever so slightly it in so many applications that I write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it the following way.

```
window.addEventListener("mousedown", function (mousedownEvent) {
    var mouseMoveHandler = 
        function(element) {
            return function(mouseMoveEvent) { 
                element.dispatchEvent(dragEvent); 
            }
        }(mousedownEvent.target);

        window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler);

    });        
});
```

So in this case on `mousedown` event you create closure that will trigger drag event on the clicked element. You do not need the array of elements that were clicked. Clicked element is already injected to the handler.

Don't forget to clean listeners on `mouseup`. Just drop the `mousemove` listener on `window`

Comment: Ah thanks, the problem lied in my misunderstanding, I do not *need* to know what elements are listening, I can just fire drag events an they won't be listened to.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wants to use the drag event, here's an example utilizing it.

```js
var box1 = document.createElement("div");
var box2 = document.createElement("div");
var box3 = document.createElement("div");

document.body.appendChild(box1);
document.body.appendChild(box2);
document.body.appendChild(box3);

box1.className = "box";
box2.className = "box";
box3.className = "box";

box1.innerHTML = "Drag me";
box2.innerHTML = "No drag";
box3.innerHTML = "Drag me";

function dragElement(event) {
    event.target.style.top = parseInt(event.target.style.top.split("px")[0] || 0) + event.dy + "px";
    event.target.style.left = parseInt(event.target.style.left.split("px")[0] || 0) + event.dx + "px";
}

box1.addEventListener("drag", dragElement);
box3.addEventListener("drag", dragElement);

// custom event logic starting here
var dragEvent = new CustomEvent("drag");

window.addEventListener("mousedown", function (mousedownEvent) {
    var mousePosition = {x: mousedownEvent.clientX, y: mousedownEvent.clientY};

    (function () {
        var target = mousedownEvent.target;
        console.log(target);

        function moveHandler(event) {
            var newMousePosition = {x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY};

            dragEvent.dx         = newMousePosition.x - mousePosition.x;
            dragEvent.dy         = newMousePosition.y - mousePosition.y;
            dragEvent.clientX    = event.clientX;
            dragEvent.clientY    = event.clientY;

            target.dispatchEvent(dragEvent);

            mousePosition = newMousePosition;
        }

        function releaseHandler() {
            window.removeEventListener("mousemove", moveHandler);
            window.removeEventListener("mouseup", releaseHandler);
        }

        window.addEventListener("mousemove", moveHandler);
        window.addEventListener("mouseup", releaseHandler);
    }());

});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;

  background-color: skyblue;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;

  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  
  font-family: helvetica;
  color: white;
  
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```